# Windows 7 ultimate, unable to detect my nexus 4 5.01

Tags: usb

My windows 7 ultimate laptop isn't recognizing my nexus 4 5.01. Tried to reinstall ADB drivers and android universal usb drivers, but no use.

can anyone please let me know how to overcome this problem?

thanks in advance!!!!!!

Comment: What USB mode do you have your phone set to use?

Answer (score 1):

Download drivers from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?8xb50uktar8096i)

source: [XDA forum - Nexus 4 driver for Windows](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/general/drivers-nexus-4-driver-windows-t1992345)

If this also doesn't work then there is discussion on [XDA forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1998650) if you are using Universal naked driver.
(OR) Above all, save data on Cloud and Factory reset.